# How to correctly put elements into an immutable binary tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree, immutability

I implemented an immutable binary tree and I wanted to know if this is the correct way in which you put elements into it. Thanks in advance.

```
BinaryTree<Integer, Integer> treeMap = new BinaryTree<>(Integer::compare);
treeMap = (BinaryTree<Integer, Integer>) treeMap.put(1, 1);
treeMap = (BinaryTree<Integer, Integer>) treeMap.put(3, 2);
treeMap = (BinaryTree<Integer, Integer>) treeMap.put(2, 2);
```

Comment: I'm casting to BinaryTree because the put method returns a Map<K, V>

Comment: Basicly, yes. Immutable force you to recover the new instance on each call. Here, you could declare your `treeMap` as `Map<Integer, Integer>` if your `BinaryTree` implements `Map` to remove the cast

Comment: Don't listen, this was stupid ... `Map.put` don't return a `Map`. This is only from your `BinaryTree` but why do you return a `Map` and not a `BinaryTree` ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it seems that is not the correct way to put elements into that inmmutable binary tree class.

You have to cast to BinaryTree because ".put" method is a method from Map, so you are basicaly using a Map object.

It seems that is a custom class that extends from Map, I recommend you to check the class code and search for methods like "addLefChild" and "addRightChild", or something like that.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think the important point is the  Immutable part, I guess OP cloned the map and put the value into the new instance using `put`.

Comment: If you share the code of the BinaryTree class, maybe I could give you a better answer.

Comment: Why? It is a .class? Where did you get that BinaryTree class? Which is its package?

Comment: Try to search the documentation of that class.

Comment: Ok, you are funny but I think you don't understand ... I am not the OP _Original Poster_ , I did not post the question !

Comment: Oh my... sorry, I didn't notice. So sorry.